# How can I setup proxy settings in c# for Google Cloud Txt-To-Speech API

Tags: c#, proxy, settings, google-cloud-speech

**How to setup a proxy in c# code for Google Text-To-Speech API.**

Does somebody knows where to put in the proxy settings for the Google TTS API in c#. Our project runs locally but not on  the server behind a firewall, so it has to go via the proxy.

Hope you have a starting point for me ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: Which version are you using, and what's your target framework? Those affect which transport you'll be using, as per https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/help/transports - and the choice of transport affects proxy configuration. (Although in general, if you set the system up with a default system-wide proxy, I *think* everything should obey that - but https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/1832 might be relevant to you.)

Comment: I use the Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 package in c#, target framework is .Net Core 3.1

Comment: But which *version* of that package? In our last major release, we changed the default gRPC implementation. Have you already tried setting the system proxy?

Comment: Version 3.0 of the package. I only have set the proxy on the server in LAN settings. Not in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

The *intention* is that if you've set the system proxy, or the `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable, that should just work by default.

However, at the moment there's a [bug in Grpc.Net.Client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/1832) that causes that to fail. (Once it's been fixed and released, we'll obviously update our dependencies for the next release of Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 and other Cloud libraries.)

The simplest workaround is probably to still use the Grpc.Net.Client implementation of gRPC, but with an additional option:

```cs
var client = new TextToSpeechClientBuilder
{
    GrpcAdapter = GrpcNetClientAdapter.Default.WithAdditionalOptions(
        options => options.HttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy("your proxy here"),
            UseProxy = true
        })
}.Build();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll start testing and let you know.